# Understanding Parse in C#

Tags: c#, parsing

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a double number");
string numberInput = Console.ReadLine();


 double number = Double.Parse(numberInput)
```

My question is what is the last line of code doing? Is it doing the same thing as `ToDouble`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The very short answer is:

Converts a string value into a double. e.g.

"2.3"(String) will become 2.3(double).

You have many choices on how to do this:

[Double.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx)

[Convert.ToDouble()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todouble.aspx)

Double.TryParse() is handy if you don't know 100% that the input string is going to be a number value.

Comment: In particular, in this given case where the input could be anything, TryParse is a cleaner way of ascertaining whether the entry will convert. Otherwise you will have to Convert.ToDouble within a try/catch. TryParse handles this for you.

Comment: Thanks guys. I was confused about Convert.ToDouble and Double.Parse. I was guessing they did similar work, but wasn't sure. Thanks for informing about TryParse()

Answer (score 4):

It is converts a `string` to `double`, the `Console.ReadLine()` methods read a string data and store it on `string` variable named `numberInput`, to convert from that string to `double`, `Double.Parse` is called we passing to it the `numberInput` string and it will convert it to double.

Answer (score 3):

"Converts the string representation of a number in a specified style to its double-precision floating-point number equivalent."

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yd1h1be.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

It's taking `String` input and interpreting it as numeric input - `Double` in this case. `String` and `Double` are quite different types. For one, mathematical operations can be performed on `Double`.

Answer (score 3):

Converts the string representation of a number to its double-precision floating-point number equivalent.

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It's calling the [Double.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt.aspx) method. According to the MSDN page it

> Converts the string representation of a number to its double-precision floating-point number equivalent.

As per [@DoctorMick's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/821473/doctormick) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831219/understanding-parse-in-c/6831452#6831452): It does the same thing as the [`Convert.ToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k.aspx) method.

In this case it's used because the code is getting a `string` from the user which can be thought of as a sequence of letters. We would want to get this into the proper type that we want to work with, which in this case is `Double`. Double has the parse method for this.

Answer (score 2):

The data read into the variable `numberInput` is a string. The last line parses this into the type `System.Double`, so that it is better typed for other operations.

There is no guarantee that `numberInput` contains a valid numeric value, in which case the Parse method will throw an exception that you can catch.

Answer (score 2):

There have been 7 different answers yet everyone seems to have overlooked the question of is it doing the same as ToDouble.  The short answer is yet, it is doing the same, in fact ToDouble calls double.Parse internally.